# Flyway - Different Migrations for certain envioronments - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

We are configuraing/starting our flyway migrations in java in our Spring Boot App.

So we have both sql and java migration files.

In certain environments we want extra migrations to run. Basically in a QA env we want to prepare the DB with data for tests.

So I know you can configure multiple migration locations in java.

So I can do something like this

```
if(isQAenv == true)
{
Flyway.configure().locations("/db/migrations/","db/qaMigrations/")
else{
Flyway.configure().locations("/db/migrations/")
}
```

My issue is with the versioning and making sure stuff gets executed as intended in all envs.

Do I need to maintain the numbering system to be the correct order?

So lets say I have the following migration scripts that should run in all envs

```
db/migrations/V1__table1.sql
db/migrations/V2__table2.sql
db/migrations/V4__table2.sql
```

And this migration only runs in QA env

```
db/qaMigrations/V3__insert_statements.sql
```

Now in a non QA env, my beacon_history_table has migration for 1,2,4. Is there any way to avoid this and have something that looks cleaner in the history table?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that using profiles, so suppose you have profiles i.e dev, prod, then you can easily define the `spring.flyway.locations` path in your properties file for that profile or in a section for that profile in `application.yml` file.

```
spring:
  profiles: prod
  flyway:
    locations: classpath:/db/migration,classpath:/prod/db/migration
---
spring:
  profiles: dev
  flyway:
    locations: classpath:/db/migration,classpath:/dev/db/migration
```

Or if you have `properties` file then you should have file i.e `application-dev.properties` and then

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migration,classpath:/dev/db/migration
```

All the paths, mentioned above should be present inside the `resources` folder.

Comment: How do you control the order in which the scripts would be run? For eg. the ones under `dev/db` folder populating table X would need to be run after the script under `/db` folder creating the table X and before the script under `/db` renaming the table to Y

Comment: The order will depend on the version you are specifying with your script, so if dev folder version is greater than the common ones it would apply later if its first then it will apply first before commons